# Set <thead> to consume full width of <table> with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table which I am trying make it's head a sticky header via CSS.

```css
#name-list {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}

thead > tr > td {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

tbody > tr > td {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table id="name-list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>Last Name</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Janet</td>
      <td>Wonder</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aaron</td>
      <td>Main</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Allan</td>
      <td>Bul</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Carey</td>
      <td>Jay</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Steve</td>
      <td>Mkl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mel</td>
      <td>Jane</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jay</td>
      <td>King</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jem</td>
      <td>Winfred</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jaine</td>
      <td>Kim</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kim</td>
      <td>Joo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jeg</td>
      <td>Manik</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Krist</td>
      <td>Jay</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kil</td>
      <td>Mofend</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wenbsi</td>
      <td>Asu</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Unfortunately after I added the following CSS properties, the width of the  no longer takes the full width and align with the body.

```html
thead {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Following is how it looks like after I have added the above CSS.

```css
#name-list {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}

thead {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
}

thead>tr>td {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

tbody>tr>td {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table id="name-list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>Last Name</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Janet</td>
      <td>Wonder</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aaron</td>
      <td>Main</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Allan</td>
      <td>Bul</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Carey</td>
      <td>Jay</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Steve</td>
      <td>Mkl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mel</td>
      <td>Jane</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jay</td>
      <td>King</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jem</td>
      <td>Winfred</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jaine</td>
      <td>Kim</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kim</td>
      <td>Joo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jeg</td>
      <td>Manik</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Krist</td>
      <td>Jay</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kil</td>
      <td>Mofend</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wenbsi</td>
      <td>Asu</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I know this can easily be done with jQuery, but I am looking for a way that's native to CSS and not use jQuery to set the width dynamically after render.

Appreciate any inputs/feedback/advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is usually achieved using a separate table for the fixed headers (refer https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html for example).

When `position:fixed` is used, the cells are taken out of the table, so will no longer be determined by the widths of the `tbody` cell contents or style. So the alternative is to set them explicitly, losing the % responsiveness.

```css
#hdr-name-list {
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 margin-top: -10px
}

#name-list {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 25px
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}

thead>tr>td {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

tbody>tr>td {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table id="hdr-name-list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>Last Name</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<table id="name-list">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Janet</td>
      <td>Wonder</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aaron</td>
      <td>Main</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Allan</td>
      <td>Bul</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Carey</td>
      <td>Jay</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Steve</td>
      <td>Mkl</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mel</td>
      <td>Jane</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jay</td>
      <td>King</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jem</td>
      <td>Winfred</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jaine</td>
      <td>Kim</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kim</td>
      <td>Joo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jeg</td>
      <td>Manik</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Krist</td>
      <td>Jay</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Kil</td>
      <td>Mofend</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wenbsi</td>
      <td>Asu</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```